# Docker Containers Restarting (132), Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Tags: node, docker, alphanet, ubuntu

I'm consistently running into a show-stopper with alphanet and docker on ubuntu. I suspect it's something I consistently overlook when setting up. My docker containers only run for a second or two and then restart (132).

Some poking around leads me to believe they restart from panic just about right away.

I have tried Ubuntu 16.04. 18.04, virtualBox MV and vmWare and even AMD and Intel. 4-6 processors and 4-8GB RAM. The result is always the same.

Other docker containers run happily.

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.6
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:13:47 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.3
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.8
  Git commit:       774a1f4
  Built:            Thu Feb 28 05:59:55 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false

$ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.17.1, build unknown
docker-py version: 2.5.1
CPython version: 2.7.15rc1
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
```

Here's an image in case it helps.

[image]

Here's a representative docker log of a container:

```
tezos@rob-VirtualBox:~$ docker logs alphanet_node_1
Current public chain: 2018-11-30T15:30:56Z-alphanet.
Local chain data: 2018-11-30T15:30:56Z-alphanet.
Configuring the node...
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
Current public chain: 2018-11-30T15:30:56Z-alphanet.
Local chain data: 2018-11-30T15:30:56Z-alphanet.
Configuring the node...
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
Current public chain: 2018-11-30T15:30:56Z-alphanet.
Local chain data: 2018-11-30T15:30:56Z-alphanet.
Configuring the node...
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
Current public chain: 2018-11-30T15:30:56Z-alphanet.
Local chain data: 2018-11-30T15:30:56Z-alphanet.
Configuring the node...
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
Current public chain: 2018-11-30T15:30:56Z-alphanet.
Local chain data: 2018-11-30T15:30:56Z-alphanet.
Configuring the node...
```

I'd be very thankful for any thoughts or suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is because of a build issue with some OCaml module that checks hardware architecture at build time  This leaks into the Docker images which throws `Illegal instruction` when run a different arch.

You can read more about it [here](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/46) and [here](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/398).

The solution is to build the Tezos Docker image yourself on the infra/hardware you want to run it. You can find a working Dockerfile [here](https://gitlab.com/abate/easy-tezos/blob/master/Dockerfile).

**UPDATE**

Added some declarative Dockerfile's [here](https://github.com/asbjornenge/tezos-docker) 
The `Dockerfile-ubuntu` is the one for you, also make sure to build on the hardware you need to run. Should work the same as the official images (using entrypoint.sh etc.)

Comment: The linked issues seem to be exactly what I'm experiencing. Thanks for that! I built Tezos from the Dockerfile and fired up a container from the image. Now it's doing the same thing - core dump. I'm still puzzled.

Comment: Strange! That solved it for me  Did you `docker build` on the same machine where you are trying to `docker run` ?

Comment: Thanks, yes I did. I'll give the updated answer a try.

Comment: @RobHitchens let me know if that ubuntu based file helped, and I can put together a proper one with a final part that will work same as the others 

Comment: In case something jumps out at you, I did `docker build .`, then `docker run -t -t tezos/tezos:alphanet tezos-node`. Working on the new suggestion now.

Comment: Ah, you are still running the old tezos image from hub then  You need to do: `docker build -t rob/tezos:alphanet .` and then `docker run -rm -it rob/tezos:alphanet`  The image name `rob/tezos:alpanet` can be anything in the format `owner/image:version` 

Comment: That works. The Dockerfile in your updated answer (alpine?) has made a container that seems stable. Is that the clue we're looking for? :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90649/discussion-between-rob-hitchens-and-asbjornenge).

Answer (score 0):

I recall encountering the same problem in alphanet months ago. I believe it turned out that the docker image had been compiled in a way that failed on some hardware configurations. I have not been able to find gitlab issues/commits for exactly the problem, but https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/220 is related.